# How do I initialize a final class property in a constructor?

Tags: constructor, dart, final

In Java you are allowed to do this:

```
class A {    
    private final int x;

    public A() {
        x = 5;
    }
}
```

In Dart, I tried:

```
class A {    
    final int x;

    A() {
        this.x = 5;
    }
}
```

I get two compilation errors:

> The final variable 'x' must be initialized.

and

> 'x' can't be used as a setter because its final.

Is there a way to set final properties in the constructor in Dart?

Answer (score 200, accepted):

You *cannot* instantiate final fields in the constructor body. There is a special syntax for that:

```
class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;

  // Old syntax
  // Point(x, y) :
  //   x = x,
  //   y = y,
  //   distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));

  // New syntax
  Point(this.x, this.y) :
    distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
}
```

Comment: I'd add to [familiarise with `final`](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) and its implication within constructors, regarding separation of concerns. What's `final` is meant to be assigned just once; so Drat provides its interface/sugar to quicker assign value to those properties (common pattern). While, if you are gonna change ´x´ property's value, then don't make it `final` (or, in case you need more operations/manipulation for setting a final, you can see the `factory` suggestion by @rkj )

Comment: Hello, what if the class Point inherits another class and must call to its parent constructor with super(x,y) AND instantiating a final field like distanceFromOrigin?

Comment: I found the answer to my question : just separate both instruction with a coma. Notice that the super() call must be the last thing.

Comment: @OliverDixon I found this is working

```dart

class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;
  final num distanceFromOrigin2;

  Point(this.x, this.y)
      : distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2)),
        distanceFromOrigin2 = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
}
```

Comment: and add ```, super(key: key)``` in the end of it.

Comment: The amount of special syntax for trivial things in Dart is nauseating 

Answer (score 98):

You can make it even shorter with `this.` syntax in the constructor (described in https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#constructors):

```
class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;

  Point(this.x, this.y)
      : distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
}
```

If you have some more complicated initialization you should use factory constructor, and the code become:

```
class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;

  Point._(this.x, this.y, this.distanceFromOrigin);

  factory Point(num x, num y) {
    num distance = distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
    return new Point._(x, y, distance);
  }
}
```

Comment: Late question but what does the factory keyword do here. I thought it was used for deciding whether to return an existing or new object, but you always return a new one here right

Comment: The factory is needed, as the Point object cannot be created right away - we first need to compute `distance`, only then we have everything ready to initialize all the final variables.

Comment: The `factory` keyword tells you that you need to construct your return value yourself (contrary to without using it it will be created for you).

Answer (score 27):

Here is a simplified summary of the ways to initialize a final class variable.

```dart
class MyClass {
  final int x; //     <-- initialize this
}
```

### Initializer value

```dart
class MyClass {
  final int x = 'hello'.length;
}
```

You'd only use `final` if the initialization could only be done at runtime. Otherwise, `static const` is better:

```dart
class MyClass {
  static const int x = 0;
}
```

### Initializer formal

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.x);
  final int x;
}
```

This is the most common approach.

### Initializer list

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyClass(int x) 
    : _x = x;
  final int _x;
}
```

This is useful when you want to keep a field private.

### Default parameter value

You can surround the parameter with square brackets (`[]`) for an unnamed parameter or curly braces (`{}`) for a named parameter and then give it a default value.

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyClass({this.x = 0});
  final int x;
}
```

This is useful if you want to make the parameter optional.

You could accomplish the same thing with an initializer list as well:

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyClass({int? x}) 
    : _x = x ?? 0;
  final int _x;
}
```

### Late initialization

```dart
class MyClass {
  MyClass(String? a) {
    x = a?.length ?? 0;
  }
  late final int x;
}
```

This is useful if you need to do more complex initialization than is allowed in the initializer list. For example, I've done this when initializing a gesture recognizer in Flutter.

### Lazy initialization

Another advantage of using `late` is that it doesn't initialize a value until you access the value.

```dart
class MyClass {
  late final int x = _doHeavyTask();
  int _doHeavyTask() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
      sum += 1;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}
```

This is useful if you have a heavy calculation that you only want call if you absolutely need it.

This doesn't initialize `x`:

```dart
final myClass = MyClass();
```

But this does initialize `x`:

```dart
final myClass = MyClass();
final value = myClass.x;
```

Answer (score 10):

I've had a similar problem: I was trying to initialise a `final` field from the constructor, while simultaneously calling a super constructor. You could think of the following example

```
class Point2d {
  final int x;
  final int y;

  Point2d.fromCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates)
      : this.x = coordinates.x,
        this.y = coordinates.y;
}

class Point3d extends Point2d {
  final int z;

  Point3d.fromCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates)
      :this.z = coordinates.z,
        super.fromCoordinates(coordinates);
}
```

```
/// Demo class, to simulate constructing an object
/// from another object.
class Coordinates {
  final int x;
  final int y;
  final int z;
}
```

Well apparently this works. You can initialise your final fields by using the above syntax (*check Point3d's constructor*) and it works just fine!

Run a small program like this to check:

```
void main() {
  var coordinates = Coordinates(1, 2, 3);
  var point3d = Point3d.fromCoordinates(coordinates);
  print("x: ${point3d.x}, y: ${point3d.y}, z: ${point3d.z}");
}
```

It should prin `x: 1, y: 2, z: 3`

Answer (score 3):

I've come to a dilemma here where I wanted to initialize a final List with no items, and a `Stream` to be defined inside the constructor (like in this case `distanceFromOrigin`).

I couldn't do that with any of the answers below, but I mixed them both and it worked.

Example:

```
class MyBloc {
  final BehaviorSubject<List<String>> itemsStream;
  final List<String> items = [];

  MyBloc() : this.itemsStream = BehaviorSubject<List<String>>.seeded([]) {
    items.addAll(List.generate(20, (index) => "Hola! I'm number $index"));
    itemsStream.add(items);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class A{
  final int x;
  
  A(this.x){
  }
  
}
```