# Dart: Error: Setter not found (when defining constructor of a class)

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, this, super

I get the following error with this very simple constructor:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage(String title, String lang, {Key key}) {
    this.title = title;
    this.lang = lang.substring(0,2).toLowerCase();
    super(key: key);
  }


  final String title;
  final String lang;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

The error message:

```
Compiler message:                                                       
lib/main.dart:34:10: Error: Setter not found: 'title'.                  
    this.title = title;                                                 
         ^^^^^                                                          
lib/main.dart:35:10: Error: Setter not found: 'lang'.                   
    this.lang = lang.substring(0,2).toLowerCase();                      
         ^^^^                                                           
lib/main.dart:36:5: Error: Can't use 'super' as an expression.          
To delegate a constructor to a super constructor, put the super call as an initializer.
    super(key: key);                                                    
    ^                                                                   
lib/main.dart:34:10: Error: The setter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'MyHomePage
```

Why is that? I don't understand what that mean.
Is there a comprehensive explanation about how to define constructors in dart? I couldn't find one on the dart.dev site.

Edit:
After editing the code to the following:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage(String title, String lang, {Key key}) {
    title = title;
    lang = lang.substring(0,2).toLowerCase();
    super(key: key);
  }

  final String title;
  final String lang;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

I have the following complaints from the compiler:

```
Compiler message:                                                       
lib/main.dart:36:5: Error: Can't use 'super' as an expression.          
To delegate a constructor to a super constructor, put the super call as an initializer.
    super(key: key);                                                    
    ^                                                                   
lib/main.dart:39:16: Error: Final field 'title' is not initialized.     
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor. 
  final String title;                                                   
               ^^^^^                                                    
lib/main.dart:40:16: Error: Final field 'lang' is not initialized.      
Try to initialize the field in the declaration or in every constructor. 
  final String lang;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is special syntax for initialising `final` variables in a constructor, answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864979/64435

Using this syntax, the working code is:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage(String title, String lang, {Key key})
      : this.title = title,
        this.lang = lang.substring(0, 2).toLowerCase(),
        super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String lang;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Comment: but I did, sorry I didn't paste this part, but I did

Comment: I just edited my question with the full code of the `MyHomePage` widget.

Comment: OK now with the full code I see what's going on, and have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code (removed the `this.` in the constructor). But I get errors (different ones) in this case. Did I miss something?

Comment: I edited my original post to show the new code and the new errors.

Comment: The initialisers go before the `{}`

Comment: sorry, but it still gives me errors. Would you be so kind as to tell me how I am supposed to write it exactly?

Comment: Thank you! I wonder where I could have learned about this syntax. It seems to be explained nowhere. How did you learn about it yourself?

Comment: Dart by example: http://jpryan.me/dartbyexample/examples/initializer_lists/ or the Dart Documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look at these.