# Use a Method in Constructor to initialize a parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I want to initialize a parameter within my constructor depending on the value of another parameter.

So depending on if the **oldEmployee** is not null I should add him to the **availableEmployees** list otherwise take the availableEmployees list as is.

The reason I want to do this within this class is, that I have read that when using Bloc I should do the computing within the Bloc's State instead of doing this in the UI.

Here is how my class looks like:

```
class ShiftCreatedOrEdited extends ShiftsState {
  final List<Employee> availableEmployees;
  final Employee oldEmployee;

  const ShiftCreatedOrEdited({
    this.availableEmployees,
    this.oldEmployee,
  });

  List<Employee> addOldEmployeeToTheAvailableEmployees(List<Employee> availableEmployees, Employee oldEmployee) {
    if (oldEmployee != null) {
      List<Employee> hList = availableEmployees;
      hList.add(oldEmployee);
      return hList;
    } else {
      return availableEmployees;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
void main() {}

class Employee {}

class ShiftsState {}

class ShiftCreatedOrEdited {
  final Employee oldEmployee;
  final List<Employee> availableEmployees;

  ShiftCreatedOrEdited(
      Employee _oldEmployee, List<Employee> _availableEmployees)
      : this.availableEmployees =
            _availableEmployees + (_oldEmployee != null ? [_oldEmployee] : []),
        this.oldEmployee = _oldEmployee;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use the following operator `:` instead of `{}` for the initialization of the properties?

Comment: @Georgios Because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42864979/7032856).